# Trying to extract XML element by attribute in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, xml

im trying to extract element by attribute from a xml file in my html page but it do not seem to work. Here is the script im using:

```
<script>

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "include/text.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
  var i = 0;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('[lang="en"]');
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = x[0].getElementsByTagName("welcome")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;   
}

loadXMLDoc();

</script>
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
  <welcome lang="fr">Bienvenue dans la section de représentation graphique des récoltes d'eau par Limace</welcome>
  <welcome lang="en">Welcome to the graphical representation of water collecting from Limace</welcome> 
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the text content from the node using `textContent` property.

You could replace this line:

```
document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = x[0].getElementsByTagName("welcome")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

With this line:

```
document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = x.item(0).textContent;
```

Comment: Is there a way to select element by tag name using the query selector?

Comment: Do you mean `querySelectorAll('welcome[lang="en"]')`? Maybe [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) can give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid the line `var x = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('[lang="en"]');`
Use **xmlDoc** variable itself for fetching the nodes. Update given below.

```
function myFunction(xml) {      
  var i = 0;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  //var x = xmlDoc.querySelector('[lang="en"]');
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("welcome")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;     
}
```